# Errors occur when trying to migrate tables

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration

Migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements("post_id");
            $table->bigInteger("author_id");
            $table->string("title");
            $table->string("short_title");
            $table->string("img")->nullable();
            $table->text("descr");
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign("author_id")->references("id")->on("users");
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

And when I run the `php artisan migrate` in the terminal I get those errors:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravelormation_schema.tables where table_schema = laraveions and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framease\Connection.php:
    // If an exception occurs when at
we'll format the error
   // message to include the bindingke this exception a
   // lot more helpful to the develoatabase's errors.
  catch (Exception $e) {
throw new QueryException(
$query, $this->prepareBin
);
}
```

• Database name seems incorrect: You're using thlaravel`. This database does not exist.

Edit the `.env` file and use the correct database` key.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#confi

```
1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framnnector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unkno

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framnnector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel", "root", "", [])
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove>
```

Comment: Did you create a database named `laravel`?

Comment: Can you include the contents of your `C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framease\Connection.php` file?

Comment: @Jad for some reason I don't have the framease folder. I have only three folders in C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\ - framework, sail, tinker

Comment: @Lessmore I'm a total newbie in Laravel. How do I create the DB in Laravel? Or I need to create the DB normally in MySQL and then somehow connect the database with Laravel? But I don't know how to link Laravel with the database

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache `php artisan config:cache` or you can drop the database and recreate a new one...

Comment: Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cptr7GdR_lc

Comment: @Lessmore thank you! The errors have gone... But now I'm getting other errors. I think I'll create a new question on those